# Can I use socket.io for simple transactions?

Tags: angularjs, http, socket.io

Simple transaction means on my website I have 8 HTML `forms` which have 10 - 15 input fields and some `forms` also have file upload option.

I am using Angular js at client side and Express js at the server side. In Angular, I am using Angular Resource for HTTP operations. This is fine, now I want to use socket.io with angular js and want to replace Angular resource by socket.io.

I have seen some examples where socket.io is used for instant messaging or some particular task not for form data submission and all. But my curiosity is that everyone wants speed and I can do the operations faster if I use socket.io.

Am I thinking in right direction or not?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by using socket.io? You can already do input verification easily on the client side with Angular. I could imagine some useful applications where you transmit input "on the fly" via socket.io and give back input hints/suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I thinking in right direction or not?

No, not really.

> But my curiosity is that everyone wants speed and I can do the operations faster if I use socket.io.

It's not clear why you think socket.io will be faster than just doing an HTTP post for your form inputs.  There is likely no appreciable difference, certainly not noticeable to the end user.  If you were doing a zillion of these from the same client to the same server in a relatively short period of time, then perhaps it might make more sense to use a socket.io connection just to avoid a little overhead in setting up each http connection, but if you're only doing a few from each client, that difference is largely irrelevant and the extra overhead of maintaining a separate socket.io connection to each client (even when the client is doing nothing) is a tradeoff in the opposite direction.

Zillions of zillions of sites on the internet use HTTP post for sending form data to their server.  It works.  It's relatively efficient.  Expressjs is built for easily processing it.  You've offered no reason why you should replace it with something else.

You can certainly use socket.io for form submissions.  With socket.io, you would just package the form data into the object of your choice and send the object.  socket.io will convert the object into JSON, send the JSON and then the receiving side of socket.io in your server will automatically convert the JSON back to a server-side Javascript object and you'll have all your form data.  So, it will work just fine with socket.io - it just isn't clear why you think that's better than just doing an HTTP post to your Expressjs server.

Comment: I was thinking that Socket.io will be faster (I am not sure) because basically it is used in chatting application which is more real time data.

Comment: @ArpitMeena - socket.io is used for chat because the server needs to "push" data to the client whenever someone else chats to you.  Thus a continuous connection is needed so the server can send the data to the client at any time.  It's used for that reason, not because of performance.  Your situation does not require that feature and thus would work just fine with HTTP.